Playwright dotenv: Unable to pull values form env file
While integrating environment variables from a .env file at the project’s root directory into Playwright, I’ve encountered an anomaly where the variables are not being recognized during test execution, as indicated by undefined values output in the terminal. This could imply an incorrect file path configuration. Despite adhering to a seemingly accurate online guide, the resolution of the issue remains elusive
The project directory hierarchy is as follows:
 - PlayWrightSampleProject
      >node_module
      >src
      >src>env
      >src>env>.env.stage
      >src>env>.env.qa 
      >{}packge-lock.json
      >{}packge.json 
      >TS playwright.config.ts

The playwright.config.ts, updated it with
require('dotenv').config();
dotenv.config({ path: './env/.env.${process.env.ENV}', });

The .env.stage contains the following details:
URL=https://sandboxrocket.nasa.co.uk
userid=Admin1@rocket.co.uk
password=Test@123

In loginSamplePage.spec.ts, the code is as follows:
test("LoginPage_TestCase", async ({ page }) =>  {
    console.log(process.env.URL);
    console.log(process.env.userid);
    console.log(process.env.password);
});

The command used for execution :
1. `PS C:\PlayWrightProject> $env:ENV="stage"`
2. `PS C:\PlayWrightProject> npx playwright test loginTest.spec.ts`

The terminal result was:
Running 1 test using 1 worker [chromium] ›
loginTest.spec.ts:9:5 › LoginPage_TestCase undefined undefined
undefined 1 passed (1.2s) To open the last HTML report, run: npx
playwright show-report


Have you tired the process explained in this documentation?
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize#env-files
